# MongoDB with Node, SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am trying to connect to mongoDB on Node with express

```
MongoClient.connect(process.env.HOTELS_DB, {useNewUrlParser = false})
```

I getting the fallowing error

```
file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/fs/mern-stack/index.js:11

MongoClient.connect(process.env.HOTELS_DB, {useNewUrlParser = true})

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
```

What am i doing wrong  here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `=` in the place of `:` you need to use colon in JavaScript object like `key: value`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

```
MongoClient.connect(process.env.HOTELS_DB, {useNewUrlParser : false})
```